# Is it possible to use a components host property to set a local variable?

Tags: angular

I have a simple component like this

```
<div #slick>
    MY COOL COMPONENT HTML
</div>
```

Only reason I'm using the a container because I need a local variable, which I then reference in my component using `ViewChild`. I know how to style the host component using `:host` in my stylesheet. Can something similar be done using the `host` attribute on my component?

Doing

```
host: { '#slick': '' }
```

yields

```
InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '#slick' is not a valid attribute name.
```

EDIT

What I mean by local variable is how it's being used in the [cheat sheet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html) - they use `#movieplayer`.

Here is my component

```
export class CarouselComponent {
    @ViewChild('slick') slickElem
    @Input() components

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        $(this.slickElem.nativeElement).slick({
            dots: true,
            arrows: true,
            draggable: false
        })
    }
}
```

and its HTML

```
<div #slick>
    <div *ngFor="let component of components">
        <item-wrapper [item]="component"></item-wrapper>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm wondering is if I can remove my `<div #slick>` container and either a) attach `#slick` to my host element or b) use other means of getting the host element.

Comment: What do you mean by a local variable. I don't get what you try to accomplish.

Comment: You can just do `constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {}` to get the reference to the `CarouselComponent` host element if that is what you want.

Comment: That works wonderfully. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do

```
constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {}
```

to get the reference to the CarouselComponent host element if that is what you want.